# Artifacts when switch to camera view and render. 3d view looks OK

Tags: rendering, artifacts

This is the picture of 3d viewport
[image]

Then I switch to Camera view (artifacts can be seen in both viewports).
[image]

And the render
[image]

You can see, that the size of the model is big (though I tried to scale it down to check and it didn't help).
Also the camera is in orthographic mode with a big Scale.
Blender 2.79 internal.

Texture is not UV mapped, but generated (sphere). And it looks different in viewport when material and render view. In case if it matters.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your clipping ranges for the viewport and camera are way to large. Don't try to make the scene match the actual dimensions of earth. The range between clipping min and clipping max is mapped to the [0.0, 1.0] floating point range which is used, e.g. to calculate the depth buffer. When the range is that large you're getting significant imprecisions.

Comment: Robert, thanks a LOT. It worked!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of [How can I prevent my text object from flickering?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53825/how-can-i-prevent-my-text-object-from-flickering)